# Matlab PHD from Generator Matrix

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, markov-chains, exponentiation

I am studying phase-type distributions. Basically a phase-type distribution is defined on a directed graph, where the nodes have exponential holding times, and you want to know the distribution of the time before arriving into an absorbing state. As such, a phase-type distribution is defined by an initial probability vector PI and a Generator Matrix D0 (which really just captures the structure of the directed graph). For given PI and D0, the distribution is formally given by

```
F(t) = 1-PI * exp(D0 * t) * TAU
```

where TAU is a vector of ones of the same size as PI. For complicated D0, it is almost impossible to find the precise form by hand, because of that matrix exponential. However, using Matlab, one gets a rapid answer:

```
syms L H t
D0 = [-L , L , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ; 
0 , -L , L , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ;
0 , 0 , -H , H , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ; 
0 , 0 , 0 , -L , L , 0 , 0 , 0 ; 
0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , -L , L , 0 , 0 ; 
0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , -H , H , 0 ; 
0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , -L , L ;
0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , -L ];
PI = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
TAU = ones(8, 1);
DISTR = symfun(1-PI*expm(D0*x)*TAU, [L H t]);
PDF = symfun(diff(DISTR, x), [L H t]);
```

Here L and H are meant to be two parameters of the subjacent exponentially distributed holding times, and t is the time. My question is, how much can I trust DISTR and PDF? Is Matlab doing this computation exactly or is it a numerical approximation? The output seems certainly analytical (although very messy). For specific L=1 and H=2, you could simply do

```
PDF(1, 2, x)
```

to get the associated distribution, with the coefficient being in fractional form. For instance, the above gives

```
12*exp(-x) - 13*exp(-2*x) - 12*x*exp(-x) - 2*x*exp(-2*x) + 4*x^2*exp(-x) - (4*x^3*exp(-x))/3 + (x^4*exp(-x))/6 - (x^5*exp(-x))/30 + 1
```

Which seems to be in "exact" form, and does not look like an approximation... Moreover, numerical simulation shows that this formula is at least approximately correct.

Thanks in advance!

S

Comment: You can try to solve your problem with simple D0 both by hand and using Matlab. Then, you compare the results and make conclusions

Comment: Simple D0, i.e. diagonal ones, such as for hyperexponential distributions, do give the exact answer, but I don't see why that would give a guarantee for more complicated ones...